# New operation on the functions of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $(M,\rho)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let ${\cal F}(M)$ denote the algebra of smooth functions of $M$. Given $f\in{\cal F}(M)$, denote by $X^f$ its gradient vector field with respect to $\rho$. Consider the following inner operation:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
*:&{\cal F}(M)\times{\cal F}(M)&\longrightarrow&{\cal F}(M)\\
  &(f,g)&\longmapsto&\rho(X^f,X^g)
\end{array}.
$$
One checks that $*$ is commutative but not associative. Some other properties are:

$$f*(g+h)=f*g+f*h$$
$$f*(g\cdot h)=(f*g)\cdot h+g\cdot(f*h)$$
$$f*(\lambda\cdot g)=\lambda\cdot(f*g)$$ for $f,g,h\in{\cal F}(M)$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

One last thing is that if $I:(M,\rho)\rightarrow(N,\eta)$ is an isometry, then $$f\ast_\eta g=(f\circ I)\ast_\rho(g\circ I),$$ so there is a contravariant functor between the category of Riemannian manifolds and the category of (abelian) magmas.

> **Questions**
>
> 1) What else can we say about the structure given by $\ast$? Should we expect divisibility and therefore have a quasigroup structure? Is there an identity element? The simple example $(\mathbb{R},euc)$, where $f*g=f'\cdot g'$, already seems to answer both questions in the negative.
>
> 2) Is there any reference of this structure in the literature? Is anyone aware of the use of this for some purpose beyond pure curiosity?

Comment: There's no more or less information in this structure than the Riemann metric.  A riemann metric gives you a bilinear pairing on vector fields in a canonical way (pointwise dot product).  Your structure is exactly this, but in the case where you have a Riemann metric on the dual tangent bundle.  A Riemann metric on the dual tangent bundle canonically induces one on the tangent bundle, so your structure is basically just equivalent to a Riemann metric.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.